# browser form validation overwrites jquery validation when I deploy it online

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I create a simple form validation by jquery validation plugin, it works in my local environment, somehow, when I deploy my app to google firebase or github, the browser default validation overwrites it. I've tried use 'novalidate' attribute on my form tag, but that blocks both validation. Anyone has ideas?

repo: https://github.com/ptchiangchloe/HTML_CSS_Test